# python vte: get the pid of the fork process

Tags: python, pid, vte

I'm using a vte term to run a bash script

```
self.child_pid = self.v.fork_command(None, ['/bin/bash', 'dPluzz-cli', dest, '-u', adresse])
```

How can I do to get the number of the pid ?
I tried

```
os.getpid()
```

but the pid is the number of my python program..

Thanks!

**Solved...**

```
id = self.child_pid
```

Comment: It looks like you already have it - `self.child_pid` should contain the numeric PID after the `fork_command` call.

Comment: oops.. yes indeed, the answer is in the question... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, instead of fork_command you now need `spawn_sync`:

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Vte-2.91/classes/Terminal.html#Vte.Terminal.spawn_sync

`spawn_sync` returns a `tuple`, second element is pid.